# Can't go through libhdfs.so in gdb env

Tags: hadoop, gdb, hdfs

my program is using libhdfs.so for hdfs read/write, I want to set a break point for debugging, but when this program runs to the point of hdfsConnect, it exits with a segmentation fault.

interesting thing is that when I run the program normally, segmentation fault does't happen at all.

what is likely the root cause? is there some runtime environment I should setup when debugging libhdfs.so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange sigsegv while calling java code from c++ through jni](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132669/strange-sigsegv-while-calling-java-code-from-c-through-jni)

Answer (score 1):

it turns out to be a JNI problem anther than a libhdfs.so specific problem, the solution can be found here: 
[Strange sigsegv while calling java code from c++ through jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132669/strange-sigsegv-while-calling-java-code-from-c-through-jni)

Comment: In your question, you never mentioned java or JNI. You also said that your program "exits with segmentation fault", which is highly inaccurate. You can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what is likely the root cause?

The likely root cause is a bug in your program, which manifests itself as a crash under GDB, but remains hidden when run outside of GDB.

This makes the problem easier to debug: the opposite (crashes outside of GDB, works under GDB) is often harder.

Your first step should be to run the program under Valgrind and make sure it's clean.

Comment: even a 3-line program just calling hdfsConnect will cause the problem. and I found it isn't a libhdfs.so error,but a jni problem, i.e. all the c++ program using jni calls java share this problem